# How to set up network in Windows 8 like in Windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, internet

In Windows 7, to set up a new network connection, you simply click on Network Connections in the taskbar, Then click the connection and click Connect.  It then asks you to set it up, and it asks you to input your network name, and security info.  Then it says “Connection has been successfully set up” and it shows you your new security key.  How do you do this same thing in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Available wireless connections should be displayed when you click the network icon in the taskbar or in the **Settings** charm's flyout.

If you need to manually setup a connection, right-click the network icon in the taskbar and choose, **Open Network and Sharing Center**, then click **Set up a new connection or network**, or choose **Change adapter settings** (in the sidebar) if looking for the network device list.